# Can we integrate the Rest Assured API Testing scripts with Jmeter?

Tags: rest, jmeter, rest-assured, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

Can we integrate the Rest Assured API Testing code with Jmeter?

I am planning to use Rest Assured for API testing but also want the same tests to carryout the performance testing with JMeter. Is there a way we can integrate the code created in testing Rest Assured with JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

If current tests are developed using [JUnit](https://junit.org/) framework the easiest option is using [JUnit Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter/) sampler, just:

1. Drop the .jar with your tests under `lib/junit` folder of your JMeter installation
2. Drop rest assured jar and any other dependencies under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
3. Add a JUnit Request sampler per test method

---

If your test design doesn't assume JUnit you can always record your rest assured tests using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Start JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. Add [this line](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.2.0/io/restassured/RestAssured.html#proxy) to the beginning of your tests:

   ```
   RestAssured.proxy = host("127.0.0.1").withPort(8888);
   ```
3. Start your tests normally
4. That's it, JMeter will capture the requests and store the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)